# Django templates error; Reverse for 'search' not found. 'search' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-templates

my layout:

```
    {% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                <h2>Wiki</h2>
                <form action = "{% url 'search' %}" method="GET">
                    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
                </form>
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href = "{% url 'newpage' %}">Create New Page</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a>Random Page </a>
                </div>
                {% block nav %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

my views.py:

```
def search(request):   
result = set()
entries = util.list_entries()
if request.method == 'GET':
    query = request.GET.get('q')    
    if query == '': #If it's nothing
        query = 'NONE'    
    if query in entries:
        return redirect(f'wiki/{query}')
    else:
        results = [entry for entry in entries if query.lower() in entry.lower()]
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
            "entries": results
            })
               
return render(request, 'encyclopedia/search.html', {'results':result})

my urls:

    from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

app_name = 'encyclopedia'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path('newpage/', views.new_page, name = 'newpage'),
    path('wiki/<str:title>', views.entry, name = 'entries'),
    path('wiki/<str:title>/edit',views.edit, name = 'edit'),
    path('search', views.search, name = 'search'),
    path('wiki/<str:entry>', views.random_page, name = 'random'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

How do i make it work? it worked before but now it just stopped working. The name in the urls matches with the name of a bar
What i have to know about url method?
I also tried to write {% url 'random'%} for a random page but it seems not working at all
When i added this to a random search url stopped working and i do not know why

Versions:
Django 4.1.4, Python 3.10.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared app_name in your urls.py file that makes it compulsory to add app_name before calling a url in django. Call your urls like this...

```
href={% url 'app_name:url_name' %}
```

So your code will be like this...

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                <h2>Wiki</h2>
                <form action = "{% url 'encyclopedia:search' %}" method="GET">
                    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
                </form>
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:index' %}">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href = "{% url 'encyclopedia:newpage' %}">Create New Page</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a>Random Page </a>
                </div>
                {% block nav %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked* sorry, thanks for help

Comment: What is the error now?

Comment: my bad, it wokred

Comment: Great, remember to call urls with app_name if you have declared app_name in url.py file even in your views and other files